# SQLite query not creating a table; no errors generated

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to create a table using SQLite however the Create Table query does not seem to be working. When i open the .db file in an online viewer there is no data/table in the file (attached). I am not getting any errors when debugging; the issue. I have been deleting old .db files and making sure the onCreate code is running.

https://wsi.li/OzOSD2tTsB1qua/

Database Helper Code below:

```
package com.example.lewis.food;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Food.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "food_table";
    public static final String ID = "ID";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "DESCRIPTION";
    public static final String INGREDIENTS = "INGREDIENTS";
    public static final String METHOD = "METHOD";
    public static final String NOTES = "NOTES";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                        DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " +
                        INGREDIENTS + " TEXT, " +
                        METHOD + " TEXT, " +
                        NOTES + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Issue 1.

The onUpgrade method is part of the onCreate method move it to be out side the onCreate method. e.g. :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Food.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "food_table";
    public static final String ID = "ID";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "DESCRIPTION";
    public static final String INGREDIENTS = "INGREDIENTS";
    public static final String METHOD = "METHOD";
    public static final String NOTES = "NOTES";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " +
                INGREDIENTS + " TEXT, " +
                METHOD + " TEXT, " +
                NOTES + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

- Note this may well just be that you dropped in the wrong code, as the code you have shown would very likely not compile.

### Issue 2.

You are likely looking in the wrong place for the database/table.

The following code as the invoking activity (MainActivity used in the code) will confirm that the database is being created as well as the table, it will also print out the location of the database :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getReadableDatabase().query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        Log.d("DBLOCATION",this.getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath());
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(
                    "DBINFO",
                    "Found a " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("type")) +
                            " named " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name"))
            );
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

When run (using only the above code) the result is :-

```
11-14 00:33:23.565 1246-1246/? D/DBLOCATION: /data/data/so53291104.so53291104/databases/Food.db
11-14 00:33:23.565 1246-1246/? D/DBINFO: Found a table named android_metadata
11-14 00:33:23.565 1246-1246/? D/DBINFO: Found a table named food_table
11-14 00:33:23.565 1246-1246/? D/DBINFO: Found a index named sqlite_autoindex_food_table_1
```

That is the above code creates the database, the table and the index on the food column (unless it already exists) and then logs some information about the actual database.

- Note the DBLOCATION will depend upon your package and will not be the same as above.
- You may wish to delete the App's data or uninstall the App before running any amended code.